# Bios update dependencies Asrock

Tags: drivers, motherboard, bios, updates

I am using an Asrock Z68 Pro3 Mainboard with Bios P1.60.

I want to update its bios to install Arch Linux via Usb on it.

On Asrocks [website](http://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/Z68%20Pro3/?cat=Download&os=BIOS) it states:

> Supports Intel's 3rd Generation CPU. To support Intel's 3rd Generation
>   (Ivy Bridge) CPU, corresponding BIOS, drivers and AXTU update are
>   required.

I do not have an Ivy Bridge, do I need to install those linked drivers before I attempt to update the bios itself or vice versa?

Furthermore i have a PCI-E graphics card. Do I still need to install the VGA driver?

Since Bios is a fragile component I want to make sure to make it right.

Comment: Why would you need a UEFI/BIOS update to install Arch?

Comment: Unless you need features that are available in the new BIOS version, typically there isn't any reason to even mess with it. Since you don't have an Ivy Bridge processor, there probably isn't any benefit to upgrading the BIOS.

Comment: i need a new BIOS version to enable install from usb. the current version throws an error. the solution to this afaik is an bios update according to arch forums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your motherboard already works with your CPU and drivers, then it should continue to do so just fine with the new BIOS. That update only *adds support* for 3rd generation Ivy Bridge CPUs; it doesn’t mean you *have* to have one.

Unfortunately there is no changelog on the site, nor in the `.zip` file to indicate exactly what has been changed, but the main difference is support for the newer CPUs. If others have indicated that it also fixes USB-booting, then that may be a bug-patch they added as well.

Either way, it should not *reduce* your systems ability to function. If it did, there would most certainly have been a notice to that effect.

If you are still concerned, then you can just [contact them directly](http://event.asrock.com/tsd.asp) or [post the question](http://www.asrock.com/support/forum.asp) to their technicians.